Invalid input shape for input Tensor
Tomato project
the model is building but it is refusing to train. it is saying incorrect format given for the input_shape and i have tried everything that i know possible. the model error is
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2     train_ds,
      3     epochs = EPOCHS,
      4     batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
      5     verbose =1,
      6     validation_data = val_ds
      7 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py:285, in Functional._adjust_input_rank(self, flat_inputs)
    283             adjusted.append(ops.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))
    284             continue
--> 285     raise ValueError(
    286         f"Invalid input shape for input {x}. Expected shape "
    287         f"{ref_shape}, but input has incompatible shape {x.shape}"
    288     )
    289 # Add back metadata.
    290 for i in range(len(flat_inputs)):

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().

Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32). Expected shape (256, 256), but input has incompatible shape (None, 256, 256, 3)

Arguments received by Sequential.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None


The error is related to the input data. Make sure to use
ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory and organize your dataset into a main
folder, with each class in its own subfolder. This will automatically label
the data. Then, define the convolutional model, compile it, and finally use
the fit function to train the model. I've prepared the code following this
structure. Please refer to this gist for more details.
